# directive link not populating form input with value

Tags: angularjs, drupal

I have a directive called **dgFormElement** with a **link** that dynamically generates a single form input's html string, then compiles that input into the element:

```
myApp.directive("dgFormElement", function($compile, $injector) {
    return {
      link: function($scope, $element) {

        var html = '';

        // Dynamically build the form input html string here, then...
        // ...
        // ...

        // Compile element.
        var linkFn = $compile(html);
        var content = linkFn($scope);
        $element.append(content);

      }
    };
});
```

Earlier in the app (*in another directive, not in a controller*), values have been placed into the scope, and are available in the **link's** `$scope`:

```
console.log($scope.nid); // 123
console.log($scope.title); // Hello World
```

Here is some sample html output:

```
<form id="node_edit" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope">

  <div dg-form-element="">

    <input type="hidden" name="nid" value="123" ng-model="form_state.values['nid']" ng-init="form_state.values['nid'] = nid" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope">

  </div>

  <div dg-form-element="">

    <input type="text" name="title" value="Hello World" ng-model="form_state.values['title']" ng-init="form_state.values['title'] = title" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched">

  </div>

  <div dg-form-element="">

    <button data-ng-click="dg_form_submit(form_state);" type="button" >Save</button>

  </div>

</form>
```

At this point there is a problem... when the page renders, the text input *does not* contain **Hello World**.

Leaving the text field empty and submitting the form, the following values come through to the submit handler (`dg_form_submit`):

```
{
  values: {
    nid: 123
  }
}
```

However, if I type something (e.g. `foo`) into the text field then submit the form, the following values come through:

```
{
  values: {
    nid: 123,
    title: 'foo'
  }
}
```

Why is the `Hello World` string not being loaded into the text input when the page loads?

If I remove the `ng-model` from the text input, the `Hello World` text is *loaded properly*:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="Hello World" ng-init="form_state.values['title'] = title" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched">
```

But then during form submission, the title value isn't available, only the hidden value is available:

```
{
  values: {
    nid: 123
  }
}
```

It's interesting the hidden value is always coming through, but not the text value.

**SOLVED**

After much trial and error, I found out that I only need the `ng-init` directive on hidden inputs, and that I was accidentally overwriting `$scope.nid` and `$scope.title` much later in the app.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have set `ng-model` on the input element. When angular compiles the html it will set the input value based on the value of `ng-model`.

I see that you have set the initial value of `form_state.values['title']` to `title` but where is this variable `title` defined?

If you want to initialize it with a hard coded string then you have to specify it in quotes.

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="form_state.values['title']" ng-init="form_state.values['title'] = 'Hello World'" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched">
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/sHS2qvkY0ctXlB1ge5gn?p=preview

Comment: To clarify, the `title` variable is set earlier in the app, and is available in `$scope.title` during the `link` function. However, if I comment out the setting of `$scope.title`, no difference occurs. It won't be feasible to hard code the value for all inputs, so I will try your `ng-model` suggestion. I'm also not using any `ng-controllers`, because AFAIK they will be deprecated in Angular 2.x.

Comment: I've updated my question to describe the removal of `ng-model` from the text input.

Comment: I added the title variable to controller scope and it is working fine as well.

Comment: This is very close to a solution. Now, is it possible to do it without the `ng-controller`, i.e. in another directive? I've updated my question to reflect the fact that the values are placed into the `$scope` in another directive that runs before the dgFormElement directive.

Comment: Yes you can do it if the parent directive has its own scope. Otherwise it will use the scope of parent directives parent controller.